# CSS Position Problem : Want the Table to position to TOP

Tags: css, html-table, position, css-float

I want the Right-hand side Table to touch top
[image: 1]

### my markup and css

```css
.leftDev {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vl {
  border-left: 4px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  float: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightDev {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftDev"></div>
<div class="vl"></div>
<div class="rightDev "></div>
```

I kept `top:0;` still it is just below The form. Help to reach the table to top.

Comment: Can you provide the whole code for both html and css?

Comment: leftDev contains Form. VL = vertical line. rightDev contains table

Comment: I would really like to help with your problem but the code you provided is still not enough to recreate the issue.

Comment: If you will try to use just that code that you provide, and just add a simple form and table with a border=2, maybe you'll be able to understand a little why the table is on the middle.

Comment: I added but it says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: The html and css you provided is not enough to recreate your issue, it's missing some css and html. Look, try to copy this code https://pastebin.com/6QprhYmw, maybe you'll find something that you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your `.leftDev`, `.vl` and `.rightDev` are taken width more than **100%** consequently `.rightDev` will render in a new row ....

when you set a width to **49%** for each div you forget about **10px padding** to solve this issue and make the padding take in consideration with the given width
just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.leftDev` and `.rightDev`

```css
.leftDev {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:black;
}

.vl {
  border-left: 4px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  float: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightDev {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftDev"></div>
<div class="vl"></div>
<div class="rightDev "></div>
```

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; <~~  this solve the issue.Thanks ibram Reda